# When am trying to create a new spot instance through python code am getting this error can any one help me out

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

Unble to create EC2 Instance due to `socket.getaddrinfo` info

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\workspace\test1\main.py", line 131, in <module>
main()
File "C:\workspace\test1\main.py", line 101, in main client =create_client()
File "C:\workspace\test1\main.py", line 19, in create_client regions= client.get_all_regions()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\boto\ec2\connection.py", line 3477, in get_all_regions[('item', RegionInfo)], verb='POST')
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 1170, in get_list response = self.make_request(action, params, path, verb)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 1116, in make_request return self._mexe(http_request)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 1030, in _mexe raise ex
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 943, in _mexe request.body, request.headers)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request self.endheaders(body)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output self.send(msg)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send self.connect()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\boto\https_connection.py", line 119, in connect sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 494, in create_connection for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 22, SOCK_STREAM):
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo for res in_socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):socket.gaierror: [Errno 10047] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**gaierror** is related to **g**et**a**ddr**i**nfo and your problem is probably due to the hostname. If not yet, you may try to change for the IP address, which doesn't need to be resolved.

If you can post details about your code, may be helpful. (I know this may be not a full answer, but I can't comment yet)

Comment: def wait_for_up(client, inst):
 print ('Waiting for instance to come up')
   while True:
      s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
       if inst.ip_address is None:
        inst = get_existing_instance(client)
         try:
           if inst.ip_address is None:
             else:
                   s.connect((inst.ip_address, 22))
                   s.shutdown(2)
                   print ('Server is up!')
                                print ('Server Public IP - %s' % inst.ip_address)
                  break
                except:
     sleep(10)

Comment: What are you getting into `inst.ip_address`? You should consider updating your question adding these codes.

Comment: inst.ip adress for getting client ip address